# How to convert List<FirstObject[]> to List<SecondObject> with Stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have lists:

```java
List<Point[]> listPoints = ...
List<Quadrangle> quadrangles = ...
```

How convert `List<Point[]>` to `List<Quadrangle>` with Stream in Java 8?

Need replace:

```java
for(Point[] groupPoints : listPoints) {
            quadrangles.add(new Quadrangle(groupPoints));
}
```

Object `Quadrangle` has the constructor:

```java
public Quadrangle(Point[] points) {
        this.p1 = points[0];
        this.p2 = points[1];
        this.p3 = points[2];
        this.p4 = points[3];
    }
```

I tried this:

```
List<Quadrangle> quadrangles = listPoints.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(o -> new Quadrangle(o)));
```

but this doesn't work for me. I get error:

```
Required  type:Point[]
Provided: <lambda parameter>
```

I thought that the `lambda parameter` `o` is the array `Point []`, but isn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this.

- Stream the list of point arrays.
- Map to a new instance of Quadrangle (this applies the constructor argument)
- return a list of Quadrangle.

```
List<Quadrangle> quads = listPoints.stream()
.map(Quadrangle::new)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```